# can I use google recaptcha in a android library

Tags: android, recaptcha

I know that one can integrate recaptcha in an app, but I want to know If I could use it in a library that would be used by hundreds of apps for example and not require to add the package names individually for each app that uses my library?

Answer (score 0):

Each app would still need to setup their own recaptcha account to get an API key etc.

But you could make the recaptcha library a dependency of your library in gradle so for any app using your library the recaptcha library is also installed.